# Replace for loop by using a boolean matrix to perform advanced indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

When dealing with a 3-dimensional matrix "M" of dimensions (A, B, C), one can index M using 2 vectors X with elements in [0, A) and Y with elements in [0, B) of the same dimension D.

More specifically, I understand that when writing

```
M[X,Y,:]
```

we are taking, for each "i" in D,

```
M[X[i], Y[i], :],
```

thus producing a DxC matrix in the end.

**Now suppose**

```
X is a numpy array of dim U, same concept as before
this time Y is a matrix UxL, where each row correspond to a Boolean numpy array 
(a mask)
```

and look at the following code

```
for u in U:
    my_matrix[Y[u], X[u], :] += 1  # Y[u] is the mask that selects specific elements of the first dimension
```

**I would like to write the same code without the for loop.** Something like this

```
np.add.at(my_matrix, (Y, X), 1) # i use numpy.ufunc.at since same elements could occur multiple times in X or Y.
```

which unfortunately returns the following error

> IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is L but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

This issue can also be found when performing assignment

```
for u in U:
    a_matrix[u, Y[u], :] = my_matrix[Y[u], X[u], :]
```

Do you know how I can address this problem(s) in an elegant way?

Comment: Could you give a minimal working example, maybe with a 3x3x2 matrix or something easy to visualize?

Comment: To make sure I understand, `Y` is a 2D matrix, and `Y[u]` is the 1D mask that indexes the `Y` dimension. But `X` is a 1D matrix, so `X[u]` is a single element. In other words, in the working for loop, each time you are adding 1 to a single column only at the rows indicated by `Y` throughout all three dimensions. So `Y[u]` may indicate some of the same rows, which would correspond to adding 1 multiple times to those elements. Is that correct?

Comment: If so, I think the best way would be to do something like collapse down the `Y` vector first and calculate a sum matrix to add to the whole thing.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds correct. I have updated the question with a further assignment problem,

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way of simply using the usual nd-array-shaped fancy indexing is unlikely to work for your problem. Here's why I'm saying this: `Y` has boolean rows which tell you which indices to take along the first dimension. So `Y[0]` and `Y[1]` might have a different amount of `True` elements, thus the rows of `Y` would slice subarrays with varying length along the first dimension. In other words, your array-shaped indices can't be translated to a rectangular subarray.

But if you think about what your indexing arrays mean, there's a way out. The rows of `Y` exactly tell you which elements to modify. If we clutter all the indices to a huge collection of 1d fancy indices, we can pinpoint each `(x,y)` point along the first dimension which we want to index.

In particular, consider the following example (sorely missing from your question, by the way):

```
A = np.arange(4*3*2).reshape(4,3,2)
Y = np.array([[True,False,False,True],
              [True,True,True,False],
              [True,False,False,True]])
X = np.array([2,1,2])
```

`A` is shape `(4,3,2)`, `Y` is shape `(3,4)` (and the first and last rows are identical on purpose), `X` is shape (3,)` (and the first and last elements are identical on purpose). Let's turn the boolean indices into a collection of linear indices:

```
U,inds = Y.nonzero()
#U: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])
#inds: array([0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3])
```

As you can see, `U` are the row indices of each `True` element in `Y`. These are the indices that give the correspondence between rows of `Y` and elements of `X`. The second array, `inds` are the actual linear indices (for a given row) along the first dimension.

We're almost done, all we need is to pair up the elements of `inds` with the corresponding index from `X` for the second dimension. This is actually pretty easy: we just need to index `X` with `U`.

So all in all, the following two are equivalent looping and fancy-indexing solutions to the same problem:

```
B = A.copy()
for u in range(X.size):
    A[Y[u],X[u],:] += 1
U,inds = Y.nonzero()
np.add.at(B,(inds,X[U]),1)
```

`A` is modified with a loop, `B` is modified using `np.add.at`. We can see that the two are equal:

```
>>> (A == B).all()
True
```

And if you take a look at the example, you can see that I intentionally duplicated the first and third bunch of indices. This demonstrates that `np.add.at` is working properly with these fancy indices, complete with accumulating indices that appear multiple times on input. (Printing `B` and comparing with the initial value of `A` you can see that the last items are incremented twice.)